# Is there a "hereditary" construction for $L$?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, constructibility

Recall that $L$, Godel's constructible universe is constructed by defining the following hierarchy:

$L_0=\varnothing$, for a limit ordinal $\delta$, $L_\delta=\bigcup_{\alpha<\delta}L_\alpha$, and $L_{\alpha+1}=\operatorname{Def}^1(\langle L_\alpha,\in\rangle)$ (where the $^1$ denotes first-order definability).

On the other end of spectrum, we define $\sf HOD$ the class of hereditary ordinal-definable sets as the class of sets which are ordinal definable, i.e. there is some formula $\varphi(x,\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ such that only a single $x$ satisfies with a given sequence of ordinal parameters, and that their transitive closure is made entire of ordinal definable sets.

But Scott and Myhill showed that if you replace $\operatorname{Def}^1$ by $\operatorname{Def}^2$ (second order definability) in the constructible hierarchy, you get $\sf HOD$ as well. So we can construct $\sf HOD$ in two ways:

1. Take a "definability closure" for second-order logic.
2. Define a property, then consider those which have this property in a hereditary fashion.

---

> **Question.** Is there some natural definable class which is similar to $\sf OD$, that when taking the "hereditary" subclass we get $L$?

Comment: I’m shooting in the dark, but how do hereditary ordinal $\Sigma_1$-definable sets look like?

Comment: Emil, what precisely do you mean by that?

Comment: Take the definition of HOD just like above, but require $\varphi(x,\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ to be a $\Sigma_1$-formula.

Comment: @Emil: Do you mean taking $\sf OD$ with only $\Sigma_1$ formulas, and then considering those whose transitive closure is made of such sets, and it is itself $\Sigma_1$-definable, or construct by recursion a continuous hierarchy where at each step you add the $\Sigma_1$-OD subsets of the previous collection? (The point is that I'm not 100% clear that these two approaches are equivalent when talking only about $\Sigma_1$ formulas.)

Comment: The first one. The second one doesn’t seem to make much sense to me.

Comment: Well, the second one is really the same (at least when considering all the formulas), since you really just construct $V_\alpha\cap\sf HOD$ one step at a time. In either case, I should have opened with it in my first comment: I have no idea. :-)

Comment: What do you mean by "similar"? I think that $L$ is "similar" to OD, because both are defined using quite explicitly definability relations. (And clearly "hereditarily in L" is the same as "in $L$".)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek The class of hereditarily ordinal $\Sigma_1$-definable sets can be more than $L$. For example, start in $L$ and let $T$ be a Suslin tree with the unique branch property (see http://jdh.hamkins.org/degreesofrigidity/), which means that if we force to add an $L$-generic branch $b$, then $L[b]$ has only one branch though $T$. In $L[b]$, the branch $b$ is hereditarily ordinal $\Sigma_1$-definable, since $T$ is ordinal $\Sigma_1$-definable (being in $L$) and $b$ is the unique branch through it. So in $L[b]$, we get $\text{HOD}_{\Sigma_1}=L[b]$.

Comment: @Goldstern: I mean that in the sense that $\sf HOD$ can be defined as first defining some class $X$ which is not transitive, then taking the class of "hereditarily $X$". So in the case of $\sf HOD$ we have that $X=\sf OD$. But is there some $X$ for which $hX=L$ (in $\sf ZFC$, of course, not a consistency result!)

Comment: Asaf, you might like the class Imp (for "Implicitly definable") in my paper with Cole Leahy: http://jdh.hamkins.org/algebraicity-and-implicit-definability. The class Imp is obtained by iterating implicit definability, rather than merely definability, and we prove that it can be larger than L.

Comment: @Joel, I do recall this class. Unfortunately I'm looking for something whose "hereditary subclass" is always $L$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Meanwhile, on countable sets, your idea works, since $L_{\omega_1^L}\prec_{\Sigma_1} V$ by Levy-absoluteness. So any $\Sigma_1$-definable set with countable ordinal parameters (countable in $L$) will be in $L$. I suppose this could be seen as a partial answer to Asaf's question, up to $\omega_1^L$.

Comment: @Joel: Thanks for the explanation, that’s interesting.

Comment: @Emil: While we're on the subject, let me say that what I said before was nonsense and a step-by-step construction is most definitely not $V_\alpha\cap\sf HOD$. Sorry 'bout that. :-)

Comment: I guess the $L[b]$ example also shows that the hereditarily ordinal $\Delta_1$-definable sets can exceed $L$, since $b$ is actually $\Delta_1$-definable from ordinal parameters.

Comment: Well, $\Sigma_n$-definable elements are $\Delta_n$-definable by the usual argument, aren’t they?

Comment: Is that true? What is the usual argument?

Comment: @Joel, the "usual argument" as I know it is for $L$-like construction, where if a set is definable (by a particular type of formula like $\Sigma_n$ or $\Sigma^1_2$) then its complement is definable the next step. I don't know if that is what Emil meant, or if that works here.

Comment: I understood @EmilJeřábek to be talking about definability in $V$, not just $L$.

Comment: @Joel: Yes, I meant definability in $V$. The argument, which works for arbitrary first-order structures, is that if $a$ is definable by a formula $\phi(x)$, it is also definable by the formula $\forall y\,(\phi(y)\to y=x)$.

Comment: Thanks! One may hope to learn something new every day...

Comment: My argument seems to be wrong at some point so I deleted it. Let me think on it a little more.

Comment: @Mohammad: Sure! Thanks for thinking this question over! :-)